# How to update bulk articles using php script without content modification

Tags: php, articles, joomla-3.6

I want to edit/update Joomla article using an external script. The assets table has been broken and for that I used ACL Manager to fix it. But there are some missing assets for which I need to open and `re-save the articles` without modifying anything. `No content modification` I can do this manually but when data is heavy, then opening and re-saving each and every article would be hectic.

Therefore, I want to create a php script using which I can update the articles or just save them as it is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem of manual update using the following script. In this case, I only wanted to update the missing assets articles mentioned in ACL manager. There were about 1000 such articles.

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
    defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();


$basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_content';
require_once $basePath.'/models/article.php';
$article_model =  JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article','ContentModel');

require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_aclmanager/models/diagnostic.php';
$acl_model =  JModelLegacy::getInstance('Diagnostic','AclmanagerModel');
$missingAssets = $acl_model->getMissingAssets();

/*
 * @missingAssets : returns array of issues present in asset table
 *
*/
foreach ($missingAssets as $key => $value) {
    //to check and update only articles. The array might contain type of category and module as well
    if($value->type == 'article'){
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*')->from('#__content')->where('id='.$value->id.'');
        $update_data = $db->setQuery($query)->loadAssoc();
        $article_model->save($update_data);
        echo '<p>article updated - '.$value->id.'</p>';
    }
}
```

I have added more description in [github](https://github.com/ruchikanagarkar/Update-bulk-articles-in-joomla-using-php) . So, one can refer this also if more guidance is needed.